# How to open a browser within VSCode just like another editor tab

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For a VSCode extension i want open browser within VSCode not externally, wherein i can load some URL (https://developers.redhat.com/)

I tried looking into various options to achieve it in VScode extension, what i came across is with help of webview i.e `'vscode.previewHtml'` we can pass html content which would be rendered with in VSCode editor tab, but what i have is url to load. Can pass it to iframe but i can't open it in iframe

Another option is to open it in browser but it opens external browser.

what i need is to open a browser within IDE (VSCode), experience should be similar to what we get for `'vscode.previewHtml'`

or as we see in IDEs like eclipse where browser window is opened right inside IDE.

As we can see below

[image]

Please give inputs, suggestions

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking here. As it stands, your current question is difficult to parse.

Comment: @ifconfig does it give some clarity now?

Comment: previewHTML takes html content to render , i want to load some url ( https://developers.redhat.com/ ) i can use iframe in previewHTML but is there a way load/open browser within VSCode?

Comment: *There you go!* That is what you should have asked in your question the first time. Are you writing your extension in TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: @ifconfig i tried to rephrase my question , sorry about that. Am writing in typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open HTML file in vscode like in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301694/how-to-open-html-file-in-vscode-like-in-browser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to render your html you can use the `WebView API`:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview

Comment: That is a only a "hint as to how to build it", not a "here is a plugin that does it" or a "there is no such tool/feature available now" answer.

Comment: Is it possible to open a 3rd party URL like `https://google.com` using webview? The documentation only talks of rendering locally saved HTML.

Comment: @secretshardul Yes you can, you will have to use an `<iframe>` element. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786094/8132485.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible now with Microsoft's extension 'Live Preview'. Open command palette (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and search for "Simple Browser: Show".

This is how it looks:

[image: vscode browser tab]

Comment: That is an extension.

Comment: If it is an extension, I can't find it and I don't recall installing it. Works in my VS Code (and does just what it's supposed to)

Comment: I spoke too soon. It has many flaws. For example, you can only open one tab of this Simple Browser at a time, and it doesn't let you do simple things like copy-and-paste. The utility of this extension is significantly less than what I was expecting.

Comment: Can it show an inspector?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro | No, it can't.

Comment: Command palette is "Cmd + Shift + P" on macos.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Yes. You can use the VSCode developer tools, under 'Help' (@Eray Erdin)

Comment: @LukasKroess | Did you verify that that developer console attaches itself to the simple browser or the whole VSCode?

Comment: @ErayErdin The devtools attach themselves to the whole VSCode; The LivePreview window is a iframe element inside the vscode dom and as such you can see the LivePreview dom (be sure to enable shadowdom) aswell as use the console (you have to toggle the active console window in the dropdown on the top left corner)

EDIT: You actually don't need to have shadowdom enabled, I just checked

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has an extension in development, [Live Preview](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview).  I use it to view html codecov reports inside of VSCODE and it at least works for that.

You just search for it in extensions and add it to VSCODE

Comment: It's no longer in development. It's released and it works great.