# VSCode extensions: How do I open a new pane with an http url

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode, is it possible to open a new pane pointing to an http url? I have a server running locally (on port 8080). I want to open it as a WebView. I couldn't find anything that provides this in the [WebView API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview).

The functionality I'm looking for is similar to the snippet, except with the url opening in the VSCode editor iteself.

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.parse('http://locahost:8080'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a browser within VSCode just like another editor tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356759/how-to-open-a-browser-within-vscode-just-like-another-editor-tab)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using an iframe within webview https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview

```
 // And set its HTML content
 panel.webview.html = 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Cat Coding</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src='http://locahost:8080'> </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>`;
```