# how to use iframe in vscode webview

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

in vscode-extension webview(catcoding), i want load external webpage(like google,..),

i tried

```
    panel.webview.html ="<html>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.google.com/"></meta>
    </html>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Google has the `X-Frame-Options:` response header set to `SAMEORIGIN` (`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`) which notifies browsers if they are allowed to render the requested page inside `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` HTML elements, that are not hosted on the same domain.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

**But** this can be bypassed/overridden by appending `webhp?igu=1` to the end of the website `URL`. Like so, https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1

Then you can use the iframe like this:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height=650px" src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1" title="Google">
</iframe>
```

**The drawback** will be that this may not work for every website, in that case you can check if the website you require works with iframes by [checking for the header response](https://headers.cloxy.net/) on https://www.google.com & https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1 with latter one not including any `x-frame-options:`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `iframe` inside the webview. Just include this into the `<body>` element of the catcoding example:

```html
    <iframe src="http://dlabacov.cz" width="100%" height="400px">
    </iframe>
```

Now, not sure if it important for you to render exactly google.com website, because that particular website (and many others) refuses to render in an iframe. This is why I used a website of my local cinema, which does not have such restrictions and I use it for such tests. So if you want to display a website that is under your control, perhaps you can setup the policies to allow it to be rendered in an iframe.